# How can I setup proper EF generated model classes from database?

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework

I am doing a project on my own. Let me describe it: I am trying to setup a social network database in SQL Express with Entity Framework. I created the tables in the database and then used EF to generate the models from the database. It generates it, but a bit wrong.

I mainly focused on the Friendhip part of the database. I created the table called USERS. Then I made a table called FRIENDSHIP. The FRIENDSHIP table has 3 attributes. These are FriendShipID, User1_ID and User2_ID. The FriendShipID is a primary key, the others are FOREIGN KEYs referencing to USER table UserID. When I generate the model in VS with EF, in the USER class there are properties:
`public virtual ICollection<FRIENDSHIP> FRIENDSHIP{ get; set; }` and
 `public virtual ICollection<FRIENDSHIP> FRIENDSHIP1{ get; set; }`
but I only want 1 Friendship property. How can I achieve that? Is that a mapping related issue?

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS
(
    UserID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Age int NOT NULL,
    Nickname VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE FRIENDSHIP
(
    FriendShipID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    User1_ID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES  USERS (UserID),
    User2_ID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES USERS (UserID)
);
```

C# with EF:
-In the Users class

```
public virtual ICollection<FRIENDSHIP> FRIENDSHIP{ get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<FRIENDSHIP> FRIENDSHIP1{ get; set; }
```

-In the ModelBuilder class

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<USERS>()
                .HasMany(e => e.FRIENDSHIP)
                .WithRequired(e => e.User1)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.User1_ID)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<USERS>()
                .HasMany(e => e.FRIENDSHIP)
                .WithRequired(e => e.User2)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.User2_ID)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: This is generated correctly based on the foreign keys, it feels wrong due to it being a many-to-many relationship with itself..  but it's correct. Is it causing you issues? What's wrong with it? Why do you want to remove it? Are you code-first or database-first? If the former, i think you can remove the property you don't want and it'll be fine

Comment: My goal is: a FRIENDSHIP has 2 Users exactly (not less, not more) like a Match in Tinder. I want the USERS class to has only one FRIENDSHIP property. I want to access the other User through this property. Its like a "2 to many" relationship. A **FRIENDSHIP has 2 USERS and a User has many FRIENDSHIPs**. Should I make a Many-to-many relationship and limit the no of USERS in the code?

Comment: What you have is a many-to-many relationship already.

Take User1. User1 can match with User2, User3 and User4.

however, User5 and User6 could match with User1.

So the many-to-many is, many users can match many users.

If you are code-first with EF, you can one of the properties. If you are database-first, you cannot amend the model as when you re-generate the model it'll be added back in.